# Display variable and string on same line (TI-Basic)

Tags: ti-basic

In most programming languages, you can mix and match strings with variables during output. However, I can't seem to find a good way to do so. Here is my code:

```
Prompt A,B
√(A^2+B^2)->C
If iPart(C)≠C
Then
Disp "C = √(",C
Else
Disp "C = ",C
End
Goto ED

Label ED
```

Unfortunately, with this code, it ends up printing like so:

```
A? 3
B? 5
C = √(
              34
            Done
```

This is not what I want. I would love to be able to have it print `C = √(34)`, but I currently can't find any way to mix variables and strings. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ti-basic for the ti-83 the plus (+) is used to concatenate strings.  Like this:

```
Disp "foo"+" "+"bar"
```

Will output:

```
"foo bar"
```

You must remember to convert numbers to strings using `string()` though:

```
Disp "C=√("+string(c)+")"
```

Will output:

```
"C=√(34)"
```

`Disp "C=√("+c+")"` (no `string()`) will throw an error.

Comment: I don't see an ampersand. What is the shortcut on a TI-83?

Comment: @jaysoncopes I just [looked it up](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/strings) and the *ti-83* uses the “+”, see edit.  Sorry about that, I usually use the nSpire and 89 and I presumed that they would not change such a basic command between calcs.

Comment: Thank you!! I'll try this when I get home.

Comment: I can't find the `string()` function on my ti-84 plus.

Comment: For ti92plus the concat symbol is indeed &

Comment: There's no `string()` command in traditional TI-BASIC. Only in 68k TI-BASIC which is available on the TI-89 and TI-92.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is a little late, but it might help others as well.
The `Output(...` command would be used in this case.

```
Prompt A,B
√(A^2+B^2)->C
If iPart(C)≠C
Then
Disp "C = √(",C
Output(3,7,C
Else
Disp "C = ",C
End
```

Just remember that the home display is 16x8 characters, which you may need as you plan out how and where to display your results.

Comment: Yes, this is the best way. Although just be aware that if your output is long (like many digits or decimal places), some characters might get truncated ("chopped off") and they won't be rounded.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunatelly the "string" command suggested by PGmath doesn't exist on the Ti-83/84/85/86. Actually there is no function for converting a number into a string.

But a possible solution is given here:
http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/number-to-string2

Comment: On the new OS of the CE, toString() can be used.

Answer (score 3):

Since version 5.2.0 the ti-83 and 84 (possibly others as well) got the toString( command which can be used to turn a variable into a string. This piece of code will display the variable C with the correct text on the screen.

```
Disp "Variable C: "+toString(C
```

Make sure your calculator is using this version though, otherwise you're going to have a hard time finding this command.

Comment: The TI-83, 83+, 84+, and 84+SE did not get a new OS or the toString command.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is very dead but for posterity:

If you have a TI-84+CE on version 5.2 or later, you can use the toString( function.
If you do not, if the output string will always be the same size, simply use Output(. If this does not generate the desired effect, you can use:

```
:{0,.5,1→L₁
:NL₁→L₂
:Med-Med Y₁
:Equ►String(Y₁,Str1
:sub(Str1,1,length(Str1)-3→Str1
```

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled across this thread today...

What about eval(C)?

```
Disp "C="+eval(C)
```

I know this works on a TI-84 Plus CE, and I remember my old TI-83 having this function (I think), so any calculator you might be using probably has it too. It's not *perfect* -- it can't do very long numbers, it just does scientific notation for those (note: toString does that too :) -- but it should work for what you're doing.

Comment: Please try to avoid the impression of asking a question in something which should be an answer acoording to [answer].