# In TI-BASIC, how do I add a variable in the middle of a String?

Tags: ti-basic

I am wondering how to make something where if X=5 and Y=2, then have it output something like
`Hello 2 World 5`.

In Java I would do
`String a = "Hello " + Y + " World " + X;
System.out.println(a);`

So how would I do that in TI-BASIC?

Comment: I have tried Text("Hello "X" World "Y),
Text("Hello "+X+" World "+Y),
Output(3,2"Hello "X" World "Y),
Output(3,2"Hello "+X+" World "+Y),
Disp "Hello "X" World "Y,
Disp "Hello "+X+" World "+Y,
and none of those have worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues to work out, concatenating strings and converting integers to a string representation.

String concatenation is very straightforward and utilizes the `+` operator.  In your example:
    "Hello " + "World"
Will yield the string "Hello World'.

Converting numbers to strings is not as easy in TI-BASIC, but a method for doing so compatible with the TI-83+/84+ series is available [here](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/number-to-string2).  The following code and explanation are quoted from the linked page:

```
:"?
:For(X,1,1+log(N
:sub("0123456789",ipart(10fpart(N10^(-X)))+1,1)+Ans
:End
:sub(Ans,1,length(Ans)-1?Str1
```

> With our number stored in N, we loop through each digit of N and store
>   the numeric character to our string that is at the matching position
>   in our substring. You access the individual digit in the number by
>   using iPart(10fPart(A/10^(X, and then locate where it is in the string
>   "0123456789". The reason you need to add 1 is so that it works with
>   the 0 digit.
>
> In order to construct a string with all of the digits of the number, we first create a dummy string. This is what the "? is used
>   for. Each time through the For( loop, we concatenate the string from
>   before (which is still stored in the Ans variable) to the next numeric
>   character that is found in N. Using Ans allows us to not have to use
>   another string variable, since Ans can act like a string and it gets
>   updated accordingly, and Ans is also faster than a string variable.
>
> By the time we are done with the For( loop, all of our numeric characters are put together in Ans. However, because we stored a dummy
>   character to the string initially, we now need to remove it, which we
>   do by getting the substring from the first character to the second to
>   last character of the string. Finally, we store the string to a more
>   permanent variable (in this case, Str1) for future use.

Once converted to a string, you can simply use the `+` operator to concatenate your string literals with the converted number strings.

You should also take a look at [a similar Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26391781/display-variable-and-string-on-same-line-ti-basic/) which addresses a similar issue.

Comment: Or, you can count the number of letters in the string with `length(` and use the `Output(` command to position it to its place next to "Hello ". Far easier in my opinion, and also faster.

Comment: @user3932000 The problem with your method is that you cannot count the length of a number such as `X` or `Y` in the original question, so you don't know exactly where to output any words following them.

Answer (score 2):

For this issue you can use the toString( function which was introduced in version 5.2.0. This function translates a number to a string which you can use to display numbers and strings together easily. It would end up like this:

```
Disp "Hello "+toString(Y)+" World "+toString(X)
```

Comment: Note that this is only available on the newer calculators, not the TI-83, 83+, 84+, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the length of "Hello" and "World," then you can simply use `Output()` because Disp creates a new line after every statement.